# Click handler is not firing on dynamically inserted elements

Tags: jquery, click

I am trying to write some code that fires a `click` handler on some `<li>` elements using jQuery, but it is not working. Can anyone see why?

```
<li id="savedQueriesSection" class="savedQrs selected">
<a href="#">My Query 1</a></li>

$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.savedQrs').click(function () {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

I am dynamically generating li like this

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Base/GetQueries",
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                $(".tree").append('<li id=savedQueriesSection  class=savedQrs><a            href=#>' + item.QueryName + '</a></li>');
            });
        },
        error: function (result) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: It appears to work here.. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/DfP2s/ .. are you loading jQuery...? Check your console for errors..

Comment: Is there an error on the page that is preventing this from running?

Comment: whether the `li` elements are created dynamically

Comment: also check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: I do not see any error in console. I am dynamically generating li with items. I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have mentioned in your question that you're *generating these `li`'s dynamically*.   Try to do this event using *`.on()`* event handler attachment.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(document).on('click', '.savedQrs', function () {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

Comment: oh, wow. this eliminates the need to remove/attach/create-on-the-fly handlers, COOL! WAY COOL!

Answer (score 2):

If the contents are dynamically loaded on the page then use .on() event of jquery..

[on() jquery](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

This can be done using `id`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click','#savedQueriesSection',function () {
        alert("test");
    });
  });
```

And can also be done using 'class`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on('click', '.savedQrs', function () {
         alert("test");
    });  
 });
```